# my own similar strcat() function prints only one array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, string.h

I've been trying to practice programming so I decided to try to type the strcat() function myself, or a similar one you know. I typed this code in order to proceed it and I don't know where the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main(){

  int i, j;
  char a[100]; char b[100];
    printf("enter the first string\n");
    scanf("%s", &a);
    printf("enter the second string\n");
    scanf("%s", &b);

    for(i =0; i<100; i++){
      if(a[i] == '\0')
      break;
    }


  //  printf("%d", i);

   for(j = i; j<100; j++){
      a[j+1] = b[j-i];
      if(b[j-i] == '\0')
      break;
  }

    printf("%s", a);

}
```

there are no syntax errors(I hope) 
the compiler gives me that result: It doesn't concatenate the strings, nothing happens.

It gives me the same array the same array the user entered, Does anyone has the answer?

PS: I don't know about the pointers yet.

Comment: Could you add your code here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code _there_. And not pictures of code, post the code.

Comment: Please post your code in text here, including any errors and output. It makes it easier for people here to debug it and also keeps a record of it in case people have similar issues in future

Comment: scanf("%s",a) <- do not use &a for strings, start with that , ... and post your code !

Comment: @Gar, it was like that at first, I added it thinking it would fix it but nothing happened

Comment: @MahmoudAbd-ElGhany this is an easy problem. You should be able to figure it out with a piece of paper and a pencil.

Comment: the second loop starts with `j=i` the pos. of NUL in `a`. But you assign values of `b` to  `a[j+1]`,  so the the first char changed is `a[i+1]`. Thus the NUL remains where it was and you don't see an effekt when you print `a`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Thank you very much I figured it out !!

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `strcat` as a "naive byte-copy loop" is not hard, just do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* strdog (char* restrict s1, const char* restrict s2)
{
  s1 += strlen(s1); // point at s1 null terminator and write from there
  do
  {
    *s1 = *s2; // copy characters including s2's null terminator
    s1++;
  } while(*s2++ != '\0'); 

  return s1;
}

int main(void)
{
  char dst[100] = "hello ";
  char src[] = "world";

  strdog(dst, src);
  puts(dst);
}
```

Professional libraries will do the copy on "aligned chunk of data" basis, to get a slight performance boost.